# How to use t3:// TypoLinks in TYPO3 HTML Content Elements without disabling `parseFunc.htmlSanitize` globally?

Tags: typo3, fluid-styled-content

Since the release of the security patches in August 2021 that prevents [Cross-Site Scripting via Rich-Text Content](https://typo3.org/article/typo3-core-sa-2021-013) I noticed that the output of HTML Content Elements suddenly changed in our projects. Some tag attributes and tags got removed by the newly introduced [HTML Sanitizer](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5.x/Important-94484-IntroduceHTMLSanitizer.html) (when the template is modified so that `t3://` style TypoLinks get rendered).

So simply [overriding the default `Html.html` Fluid Template](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content/master/en-us/Configuration/OverridingFluidTemplates/Index.html), changing the `<f:format.raw>` to `<f:format.html>` and adding a html decoding like in the following example is no longer sufficient.

```html
<f:section name="Main">
    <f:comment> We use this to render links and other stuff in html elements </f:comment>
    <f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
        <f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc">
            {data.bodytext}
        </f:format.html>
    </f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
</f:section>
```

The easiest way to prevent changes in your html codes output provided by HTML Content Elements is to disable the sanitizer globally by adding `lib.parseFunc.htmlSanitize = 0` to your TypoScript config, what is not ideal.

How can I disable the `parseFunc.htmlSanitize` only for this purpose?

Or is there an other solution to render TypoLinks within HTML Content Elements?

**Note:** You don't need to disable the HTML Sanitizer if you do not override the `Html.html` template!

Comment: Don't have a solution yet but maybe checkout https://forge.typo3.org/issues/95158 which proposes a new VH to just render links but leave all the other HTML untouched/unparsed

Comment: In order to copy a TypoScript block, please use `lib.parseHtmlFunc < lib.parseFunc` - thus using operator `<` instead of `=` (for scalar assignments)

Comment: @OliverHader Oh, stupid me. Thanks for pointing this out, it did the trick. I started using a reference with `=<` like described in  https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5.x/Important-94484-IntroduceHTMLSanitizer.html#stdwrap-parsefunc what did not do it's job and then ended up in this faulty TypoScript. 
I will add the answer by myself below. Thanks.

Comment: @GeorgRinger The idea with a new ViewHelper that handles `t3://` TypoLinks only would be great, more reliable and would reduce complexity by simply using `<f:format.links>{data.bodytext}</f:format.links>`  in the template.

Comment: @Ludwig Here we go `<f:transform.html>` https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/70977

Comment: @OliverHader That's nice. Maybe it would be more straight forward to have a checkbox in the html content element's form to switch on or off the link rendering. Maybe with an option to set the default by a typo constant globally. I can't remember any project where I used html elements without enabling the rendering of links. And since we have fluid styled contents the complexity of enabling this is increasing more and more. I would welcome an easy solution that could be handled by an experienced editor without overwriting templates.

Comment: @Ludwig @OliverHader Is there a solution like you mentioned @Ludwig where I can enable `t3` links in html content elements site-wide without entirely turning off any html sanitization? Would I really have to override the default html content element to do this?

Comment: @god_is_love Not as far as I know. But maybe OliverHader has more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make a copy of `lib.parseFunc` and disable the sanitizer in this copy.

```
lib.parseHtmlFunc < lib.parseFunc
lib.parseHtmlFunc.htmlSanitize = 0
```

Then use this *lib* in your `Html.html` template.

```html
<f:section name="Main">
    <f:comment> We use this to render links and other stuff in html elements </f:comment>
    <f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
        <f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseHtmlFunc">
            {data.bodytext}
        </f:format.html>
    </f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
</f:section>
```

Thanks to @OliverHader for bringing me to the right track.

Comment: Mhm... this is not a good "solution" since `f:format.htmlentitiesDecode` decodes HTML and re-introduces potential XSS again. Either use `f:format.html` ("all" version") or `f:transform.html` (v11+) for that particular `t3://` URI topic.